# OnItemSelectedListener is fired when onLongClick is pressed in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I will try to be as clear as possible.
I have a Gridview which displays images. The user is able to select multiple images in OnLongClick. The onLongClick is in the adapter. The code also has a onItemSelectedListener, which zooms the selected image at the particular position.
The problem is onItemSelectedListener is not triggered after tapping gridview at any position. And when the onLongClick is used, it triggers both i.e OnItemSelectedListener and onLongClickListener method. I tried using solutions provided earlier, which was to return true in onLongClickListener, but that didnt work either. I'm stuck here. Help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
    gvImages.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            PhotoBeans bean = (PhotoBeans) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            j = position;
            photoUrl = bean.getThumbImageUrl();
            Log.e("photoUrl", "" + photoUrl);
            zoomImageFromThumb(view, photoUrl);
        }
    });
```

//Adapter

```
     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<PhotoBeans> arrayListPhoto;


    public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<PhotoBeans> arrayListPhoto) {
        this.arrayListPhoto = arrayListPhoto;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListPhoto.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayListPhoto.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
          public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rootView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);

            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            holder.chkImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);
            rootView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rootView.getTag();

        }

        if (arrayListPhoto.get(position).isImageSelected()) {
            holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgThumb.setAlpha(0.5f);
        } else {
            holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imgThumb.setAlpha(1f);
        }


        holder.imgThumb.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (arrayListPhoto.get(position).isImageSelected()) {
                    holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.imgThumb.setAlpha(1f);
                    arrayListPhoto.get(position).setIsImageSelected(false);
                } else {
                    holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgThumb.setAlpha(0.5f);
                    arrayListPhoto.get(position).setIsImageSelected(true);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
            }
        });



        Picasso.with(Photos.this)
                .load(new File(arrayListPhoto.get(position).getThumbImageUrl()))
                .resize(150, 150)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imgThumb);

        return rootView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgThumb;
    ImageView chkImage;
    int id;
}
```

Comment: Please put your code.

Comment: why you write code of longclick in adapter

Comment: Could you please give an example of how should i change the code ?

Comment: check posted  answer medam?

Comment: hmmm...ok dear you get wrong Listener. you have to onItemLongClickListner right

Comment: if you solved your problem than dont forget to accept answer. so its helps to other also.

Answer (score 0):

put code in this on your activity like this

```
   gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {***your code here**
                return false;
            }
        });
```